# Submitting HTML form data and then redirecting to a new page using XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, html, xmlhttprequest

I’ve seen posts similar to this problem on SO, but I’ve not been able to solve my problem yet. I want to submit data from a form and then redirect to a new html page. The data submits, but I’m not redirected to newPage.html.

I think this has something to do with my action field in the form since when I remove/modify `action=“/submit_name”`, it doesn’t work at all.

This is what I’ve done so far:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<body>

<script>

function submit() {
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      window.location.href = "http://localhost:8080/newPage.html";
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("POST", "/submit_name", true);
  var form_data = new FormData(document.getElementById("myForm"));
  xhttp.send(form_data);
}

</script>

    <H1> Who are you? </H1>

    <form id="myForm" action="/submit_name" method="post" onsubmit="return submit();">
    <label for="name"> Name:</label>
    <input type="text" id="name" name="user_name">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">

</body>

</html>
```

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Your event listener isn't binding properly.

Using attributes for binding event listeners is spotty at best. Find the element and use `addEventListener`. I modified your XHR request slightly to make it log for stack snippets, but no modification is needed. Just avoid using `onsubmit=""` and it's friends.

```js
document.querySelector('form').addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      console.log("Success");
      window.location.href = "http://localhost:8080/newPage.html";
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("POST", "/submit_name", true);
  var form_data = new FormData(document.getElementById("myForm"));
  xhttp.send(form_data);
})
```

```html
<body>
  <H1> Who are you? </H1>
  <form id="myForm" action="/submit_name" method="post">
    <label for="name"> Name:</label>
    <input type="text" id="name" name="user_name">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </form>
</body>
```

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realize I'd gotten a reply. Thank you for the response and the tip!